# insert calculated field in pivot table with closedxml

Tags: closedxml

how to insert calculated field in pivot table with closedxml ?
I have been search for 2 days I get nothing.

this for example :
with syncfusion xlsio you can add as in the Picture Below
[image]
with Excel you can add as in the Picture Below
[image]

Comment: This is not supported by ClosedXML (yet).

Comment: thanks, I hope it will supported in future